# Can I extract plain text subtitles from Netflix when playing in Safari?

Tags: macos, text, subtitle

I want to select text in subtitle when playing video for learning English.

For example, when i playing video, i have a new word in subtitle, i select and translate it.

macOS 10.14 and Safari
Netflix is the source of video and subtitles

Can anyone help me determine if the words can be copied as text?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What app plays video and what is the source of your content? Netflix? Something else?

Comment: An .srt file, if any, could be opened in textedit. Also, **[** using 3 finger tap on the word **]** or **[** typing it in spotlight (cmd+ space) **]** **with** multiple Dictionaries enabled should reveal enough meaning. I am afraid I don't know about selecting a word from a running subtitle. This would need typing the word.

Comment: @bmike i play video on Netflix by Safari.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii i known how to translate on MacOS. However, when i playing video by Safari, i can't select text on subtitle of movies.